# How to add custom CSS styles in Cornerstone L.M.S

Tags: css, cornerstone

I would like to add custom CSS styles (not inline styles) in [Cornerstone LMS](https://www.cornerstoneondemand.com/).
Currently I have added the CSS in `<style></style>` tag along with each widget. But I'm not sure this is a good method to integrate CSS in Cornerstone

See attached screenshot:

[image: HTML Widget]

What are the possible ways to add custom CSS styles to the Cornerstone widget?

Comment: Of course this is not a good idea, since if you need to change a single style, you will have to edit all the widgets, where this style is defined in. Since there is no public documentation on Cornerstone, you should have a look for yourself in any documentation that was provided with the product. Usually such system work with templates/themes which may be customized.